# Cannot connect to the ManagementScope via C#. Access denied

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, active-directory

I'm trying to connect to the ManagementScope as follows:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope( @"\\mydomain\root\RSOP\Computer"));
scope.Connect();
```

But an exception (`Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)`) is thrown if the current user is not a domain administrator. How can a simple domain user connect to this management scope?

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot! It needs to be domain admin - by design.

Comment: I thought so too... But I can read Domain Password Policy settings via GPMC as a simple domain user. How can GPMC do it?

Answer (score 4):

try this.....

```
ConnectionOptions con = new ConnectionOptions();
                  con.Username = "Administrator";
                  con.Password = "Password";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + strIPAddress + @"\root\cimv2", con);
                scope.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't without elevating the domain user's privileges.

If you were writing a deployable application you could *sandbox* WMI access in a Windows Service hosting a WCF or Remoting application.

This service would be configured to run under an account with sufficient rights to access WMI. Your WCF/Remoting application would expose whatever functionality or data you need access to via wrapper methods. These methods could be called by client applications without elevated rights.

Comment: I thought so too... But I can read Domain Password Policy settings via GPMC as a simple domain user. How can GPMC do it?

Comment: @Eric - Pure speculation: if the user sets a new password you need to be able to read the password policy anyway to make sure it meets the policy.